# Expression Engine throwing a Parsing Error in the Extensions Path? Need Guidance

Tags: expressionengine

I am getting this error in Expression Engine when I am clicking on the Extensions Manager in the Utilities setting. Think anyone can help me out ... Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '&', expecting T_VARIABLE or '$' in ...

Thanks,

Jason

Answer (score 0):

probably means you've got an extension installed that has syntax errors. would recommend uninstalling all extensions and adding them back one by one until the page breaks again.

Answer (score 0):

You left out the important part of the error. After the word "in" it tells you the file and line number of the problem. Whatever file it says, if that's an extension then you might be able to reinstall it, or if you know any php you can go in and fix it yourself.

If you don't know php, but want to try posting the relevant section of code I would be happy to look at it. Just comment my post when you do so I know to come back here.

Edit: Haha, I didn't realize this was you Jason! Nice to see you on here!